# 'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'activity_main' in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am getting an error of **'Resource.Layout' does not contain a definition for 'activity_main'**. But I am confused, why it is showing this type of error. Because **activity_main** is available in **Resource.Layout**, but still showing the same error.

Here is the code,

**Resources => Layout => activity_main.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Resources => MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Label = "BSSTMatrimonial", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        WebView webView = null;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
          SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

           // webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView);
           //webView.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendWebViewClient());

            webView.LoadUrl("www.bsstmatrimony.com");
            WebSettings webSettings = webView.Settings;
            webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you include the full error in question such as the file path of the targets that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1):

Try to **Clean & Rebuild** your solution. Even you can delete & re-add `.axml` file.
If still won't work write click on .axml file

- Go to properties -->Build action
  Make sure Build action set to *AndroidResource*.

Answer (score 0):

It is a harmless error that can be ignored but you can search your files for Resource.Designer.cs. It is likely that you have two, one in your project's obj/debug folder and one in your project's Resources folder. Check for activity_main in both, it is possible that the file in your Resources folder doesn't have it.

Comment: In both Resource layout activity_main was there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been encountering this problem a lot. I think the problem lies in the fact that as xamarin is updated, it changes the variable names and file names in the templates. So if you are using code from a tutorial, if you are seeing this problem, its likely outdated. This means that you have to rename something to fit the current template.

In this case I had to change

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

to

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
```